# Default-initialized std::atomic<T*> vs lock-free stack

Tags: c++

In Williams' *C++ concurrency in action* 2nd ed. on page 213 there is an implementation of lock-free stack (shown below). It leaks nodes, and thus is  incomplete, but that's irrelevant for my question. My problem is that he does not explicitly initialize the `std::atomic<node*> head` pointer, and then derefereneces it in `pop()` function -- isn't it undefined behavior?

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic)

> The default-initialized `std::atomic<T>` does not contain a T object, and its only valid uses are destruction and initialization by `std::atomic_init`

[Moreover](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)

> Partial specializations `std::atomic<U*>` for all pointer types. These specializations have standard layout, trivial default constructors, and trivial destructors.

I suppose that I don't see something, because the (even more incomplete) 
implementation of lock-free stack on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) also doesn't care 
to initialize the atomic head pointer. Could someone please explain to me why this usage is legal?

Here is the Wiliams' code

```
template<typename T>
class lock_free_stack
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        std::shared_ptr<T> data;
        node* next;
        node(T const& data_):
            data(std::make_shared<T>(data_))
        {}
    };
    std::atomic<node*> head;  // <-- Default constructor
public:
    void push(T const& data)
    {
        node* const new_node=new node(data);
        new_node->next=head.load();
        while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next,new_node));
    }
    std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
    {
        node* old_head=head.load();
        while(old_head &&
              !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head,
                                          old_head->next));// uninitialized ptr?
        return old_head ? old_head->data : std::shared_ptr<T>();
    }
};
```

Comment: Reading from an uninitialized variable is only UB if it's uninitialized at the time you read from it. If you initialize it with a value before you read from it, it's fine.

Comment: @NicolBolas If I'm not mistaken, both functions read (and actually use) value stored in default intialized head pointer. Worse, pop() dereferences this pointer.

Comment: Also, where is the constructor of `lock_free_stack`?

Comment: @NicolBolas It seems that there is only synthetized default constructor.

Comment: It "seems" or it "is"? After all, you point out that the class is incomplete because it leaks memory. Maybe the complete version expected to have a constructor too.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Williams says that -- apart from leaking nodes -- this is supposed to be a complete implementation. In other words -- that's exactly my question, whether or not we must intialize head to nullptr in the stack's constructor.